# GmailApp service for consumer Gmail accounts?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script

I successfully set up [Gmail Snooze](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/07/gmail-snooze-with-apps-script.html) in my google apps accounts (for work) and I like it so much that I want to set it up for my personal email, too (@gmail.com).

I followed all the same instructions, but when I tried running the `setup()` function, I got the error "Cannot connect to Gmail."  Haven't been able to figure this out.

Is the GmailApp service not accessible to consumer gmail accounts?  Any work-arounds?

Comment: Works fine here. Are you sure you correctly pasted the whole function into your script editor, especially the last bracket { ?

Comment: @Greg, yes, positive.  But then I tried just sharing the script from my work account to my personal account, so I'm all set practically (although can't figure out why my personal script won't work)

Comment: maybe try to create a new scrip within your gmail account...  I don't really see how that would affect the actual script but then again it's worth trying!

Comment: The script needs to be authorized first. Press the "bug" button to accomplish that.

Comment: Still facing problems, with the installation of the script?

Comment: Can you give us an update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GmailApp works fine for consumer accounts, at least it did for my account few moments ago.